# can not find symble ... why?

Tags: java

```
class A 
{

    int i,j;

    A (int x, int y) 
    {

        i = x;
        j = y;
    }

    void show()
    {

        System.out.println("the value of i and j are " + i + " " + j);
    }
}

class B extends A // here is the error

{
    int k;

    B (int z, int a, int b ) 
    {

        k = z;
        i = a;
        j = b;
    }

    void display()
     {

        System.out.println("the value of  k is " +k);
    }

public static void main (String args[]) {

        A a = new A(5,10);
        /*a.i = 5;
        a.j = 10; */
        a.show();

        B b = new B(2,4,6);

        /*b.i = 2 ;
        b.j = 4;
        b.k = 6;*/

        b.show();
        b.display(); }
}
```

Comment: Did you import your class A in B file?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong eventually, but your question could have been a *lot* clearer. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Did you add these classes to the same file? Note that in Java all classes need to be in a file with the <classname>.java Also make sure you have the right capitals. Also you have to compile A.java and B.java

Comment: No they don't. Public classes need to be in <classname>.java. Package-private classes could have any filename.java.

Answer (score 7):

Your `B` constructor needs to call a constructor in `A`. By default it will try to call a parameterless constructor, but you don't have one - hence the error. The correct fix is to call the parameterized one using `super`:

```
B (int z, int a, int b ) 
{
    super(a, b);    
    k = z;
}
```